# How to prove that average of random forces is zero?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, stochastic-processes

The average of random is zero
$$
\langle F(t) \rangle = 0
$$

How to prove this?

Comment: You are going to need to provide some more information. In general it simply is not true

Comment: Are you asking about stochastic processes, like Brownian motion?

Comment: @J.Murray Yes!!

Comment: "The average of random is zero" is probably not what you wanted to write, but I like that phrase!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not one only "ramdomness". There are infinite possibilities for a random force. You need to specify the probability function, $p(t)$. Without it, the term random is just incompelte...

If you mean random in the sense of all directions are equally probable, then we're talking about a constant probability density. For any symmetric distribution, you can show that the mean is 0, as there will be as many times leftwards as times rightwards. You basically have to compute the definition of mean

$$\langle F\rangle= \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T F(t) p(t) dt $$